# React Remove Bootstrap button outline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a react component where I am using a span with a role="button" for a checkbox and want to remove the outline that happens when you focus on the button. Does anyone know how to do this? My checkbox code is here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CheckedIcon from 'react-icons/lib/md/check-box';
import UncheckedIcon from 'react-icons/lib/md/check-box-outline-blank';

const styles = {
  defaultButtonStyle: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  },
};

export default class CheckboxBootstrap extends Component {
  render() {
    const { disabled, style, tabIndex, onChange, name, checked, size, color, value } = this.props;

return (
  <span
    className={['checkbox', disabled && 'disabled'].join(' ')}
    style={[styles.defaultButtonStyle, style]}
    role="button"
    tabIndex={disabled ? '' : tabIndex}
    onClick={() => !disabled && onChange({
      name,
      checked: !checked,
      value: checked && value,
    })}
  >
    { checked && <CheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />}
    { checked === false && (
      <UncheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />
    )}
    {this.props.children}
  </span>
);
}}
```

I have tried adding a style and className both as defaults and props. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you explicitly set `outline: 'none'` in `defaultButtonStyles`?

Also:

You might also want to change `disabled && 'disabled'` to `disabled ? 'disabled' :  ''` to stop it adding a `"false"` className

In a similar vein :

```
{ checked && <CheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />}
{ checked === false && (<UncheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />)}
```

Can become:

```
{checked
    ? <CheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />
    : <UncheckedIcon size={size} color={color} />
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but that doesn't seem to work. I did implement your suggestions though, I appreciate that!